# I cannot execute NodeJS Script on macOS Catalina (10.15.2)

Tags: node.js, macos, macos-catalina

A year ago I created a Nodejs script to download some files from an S3 bucket, when I was running it on my old Macbook with macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) I successfully downloaded the files but recently I updated my Macbook and now I have macOS Catalina (10.15 .2) and since then I cannot longer run my script.

Normally I just had to write: `./downloader.js download` in the terminal and that worked, but now on my new Macbook the terminal returns the following message: **zsh: operation not permitted: ./downloader.js**

Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

When executing scripts with Node.js use:
`node ./downloader.js download`

Answer (score 0):

http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

Hope this solves your problem.

tl;dr: give Terminal application full disk permission. Since Mojave(10.14), all applications cannot access files without adding permission in preferences.